# JQuery get value from .resx file

Tags: c#, jquery

When I change my dropdown list, I want change a label (lblCustomer).
I don't know how to get value from resource file.Any ideas!?
`.text('"<%$ Resources:lblCustomer%>"');` this **not** work. 10x

```
 $(function () {
            $('#<%= ddlCustomer.ClientID %>').change(function ()
            {
                $('#<%= lblCustomer.ClientID %>').text('"<%$ Resources:lblCustomer%>"');

            })

        }
        );
```

Comment: are you trying to change the label to the value of the dropdown or some other value?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem to this.  What I end up doing is registering a startup script that reads the values from the .resx file into a variable in javascript.  Then I just reference the javascript variables as I need to.

C# Code:

```
 StringBuilder colModel = new StringBuilder();
colModel.AppendFormat("var uiStrings = {{ captureStart: \"{7}\", captureOK: \"{0}\", captureRegister: \"{1}\", captureBad: \"{2}\", captureRegisterBad: \"{8}\", gridTitle: \"{3}\", gridIsCap: \"{4}\", gridNoCap: \"{5}\", gridDelete: \"{6}\", captureDiffUser: \"{9}\" }};",
                    this.GetLocalResourceObject("capOK").ToString(), this.GetLocalResourceObject("capRegisterOK").ToString(), this.GetLocalResourceObject("capBad").ToString(),
                    this.GetLocalResourceObject("gvCaption").ToString(), this.GetLocalResourceObject("gvIsCaptured").ToString(), this.GetLocalResourceObject("gvIsNotCaptured").ToString(),
                    this.GetLocalResourceObject("gvDelete").ToString(), this.GetLocalResourceObject("capStart").ToString(), this.GetLocalResourceObject("capRegisterBad").ToString(),
                    this.GetLocalResourceObject("capDiffUser").ToString());


 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "initData", colModel.ToString(), true);
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#status").html(uiStrings.captureDiffUser);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I prefer this approach to the <%= approach by far. Personally I go one step further and create an object and register it as JSON with my own extension method.

Comment: I not sure what you mean by "doesn't work," when that code is taken from a working solution of mine.  One thing I should note, is that I have `var uiStrings = { };` already declared in my JS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetGolabalRessourceObject Function.

```
$(function () {
        $('#<%= ddlCustomer.ClientID %>').change(function ()
        {
      $('#<%=lblCustomer.ClientID%>').text('<%=GetGlobalResourceObject("lblCustomer")%>');

        })
    }
    );
```